Why does my C++ code with a type mismatch compile without warnings using the GCC "-Wall" flag?
I have the following code:
#include <iostream>

char add(char a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long a = 100000000;
    long long b = 20;

    int x = add(a, b);

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

And I don't understand why does my code compile without any warnings.
Shouldn't the GCC compiler with the -Wall flag give me a type mismatch error?

Note: Sometimes, but not this time, you have to force the compiler to take a much closer look at your code to get warnings for mistakes and have to turn on or turn up the optimizer .

This is not an error it is a valid implicit conversion, although it involves narrowing the type. You can get warning about this with e.g. -Weverything in clang which will emit
<source>:13:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'char' [-Wimplicit-int-conversion]
   13 |     int x = add(a, b);
      |             ~~~ ^
<source>:13:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
   13 |     int x = add(a, b);
      |             ~~~    ^    


Thank you. But then my next question would be: why does function overloading exist if the compiler converts the types anyway?

Function overloading is slightly orthogonal to implicit conversions. The fact that a parameter is implicitly convertible will just mean that the overload is a valid candidate for overload resolution, though there is still a ranking when resolving which specific overload to choose, and implicit conversions are part of the criteria. See the "Best viable function" section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

@Noah - Also, the type conversion comes from C, which doesn't have that many types, and no function overloading. C++ just kept it for compatibility.

@BoP -- C++ has implicit type conversions because they are useful. You really don't want to have to write a cast every time you need a conversion.

@PeteBecker: Rust begs to differ. ;-) (Yes, it's a royal pain in Rust sometimes, but it does protect against all sorts of issues like these)

@ShadowRanger -- I deliberately didn't accuse people who like casts of wanting to write code in Pascal.  But mostly my point was that C++ didn't "[keep] it for compatibility"; it's a much deeper design decision than that.

-Wall doesn't include every warning.  If you want this particular one, you should explicitly ask for it with -Wconversion:
78623032.cpp: In function ‘char add(char, int)’:
78623032.cpp:5:14: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ may change value [-Wconversion]
    5 |     return a + b;
      |            ~~^~~
78623032.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
78623032.cpp:13:17: warning: conversion from ‘long long int’ to ‘char’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   13 |     int x = add(a, b);
      |                 ^
78623032.cpp:13:20: warning: conversion from ‘long long int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   13 |     int x = add(a, b);
      |                    ^

